# Unable to import Preprocesing python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using spyder Anaconda. I am unable to import

```
 from preprocessing import parse_annotation,BatchGenerator
```

I tried to install preprocssing using,

```
 pip install preprocessing
```

got following error,

```
Requirement already satisfied: preprocessing in
 c:\users\shahik\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.1.13)

Requirement already satisfied: nltk==3.2.4 in c:\users\shahik\anaconda3\lib\site-
packages (from preprocessing) (3.2.4)

Requirement already satisfied: sphinx-rtd-theme==0.2.4 in 
c:\users\shahik\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from preprocessing) (0.2.4)

Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\shahik\anaconda3\lib\site-packages 
(from nltk==3.2.4->preprocessing) (1.10.0)

notebook 5.3.1 requires terminado>=0.8.1, which is not installed.

notebook 5.3.1 has requirement jupyter_client>=5.2.0, but you'll have jupyter-
client 5.0.1 which is incompatible.

notebook 5.3.1 has requirement jupyter_core>=4.4.0, but you'll have jupyter-core 
4.3.0 which is incompatible.
```

Also tried to install from conda commands but failed. How can I solve these compatibility or other issues?

Comment: HAve you tried using virtualenv? It works for me, Python 3.5.2

Comment: How are you launching your python application? Make sure the interpreter is the same in which you have installed preprocessing.

Comment: please show the error you get when the import statement is executed.

Comment: This can happen if the "kernel" you choose in Jupyter is not the same as that in the environment in which you installed the package. To compare the two, try running `where python` on the command line where you installed the package, and `!where python` in your Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Using python 3.5 in virtualenv                                                       
(preprocessing) C:\Users\shahik\Anaconda3>pip install preprocessing
Requirement already satisfied: preprocessing in c:\users\shahik\anaconda3\envs\preprocessing\lib\site-packages (0.1.13) 
where python command gives, 
C:\Users\shahik\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\shahik\Anaconda3\envs\preprocessing\python.exe
C:\Users\shahik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\python.exe

Comment: from preprocessing import parse_annotation,BatchGenerator
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-1bfd77040982>", line 1, in <module>
    from preprocessing import parse_annotation,BatchGenerator

ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_annotation'